# IndexError: string index out of range - if function with dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I try to eliminate brackets and unnecessary marks in the dataframe.

Here's what my data look like:

```
df["address"]

index  address
0       (#)(△)Kaohsiung City
1       (△)New Taipei City
2       (O)Chiayi City
.
.
```

Currently I'm using this:

```
def reshape_address(addr):
    if addr[0] == "(":
        return addr.split(")", 1)[-1]
    else:
        return addr

def run_reshape_addr(text):
    text["address"] = text["address"].apply(reshape_address)
    text["address"] = text["address"].apply(reshape_address)
    text["address"] = text["address"].apply(reshape_address)
#run three times in order to get rid of multiple brackets

run_reshape_addr(df)
```

Somehow I got the **IndexError: string index out of range.**
However, a partial of data have been executed successfully after this run even the error message pops up.

How can I revise this? And why were some of the data still being executed under this circumstance? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have a record with an empty string, so when you look if it starts with a `(`, it throws the `IndexError`.

You can fix this by simply checking if the string is empty first.

```py
def reshape_address(addr):
    if addr and addr[0] == "(": # Check if addr is truthy
        return addr.split(")", 1)[-1]
    else:
        return addr
```

Comment: Thank you. I just checked the records and found one record with only "(X)" in the cell. As it's not completely blank, I supposed it gets an error when I use split and try to get the last value in the list. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of all the preceding `(...)` in one go with `rpartition`:

```py
def run_reshape_addr(text):
    _, _, text["address"] = text["address"].rpartition(")")
```

```py
a = "Correct-Horse-Battery-Staple"
b = "Troubadour"

a.rpartition("-") == ("Correct-Horse-Battery", "-", "Staple")
b.rpartition("-") == ("", "", "Troubadour")
```

Comment: Hi, based on your suggestion, I finally come out with this:
text["address"] = text["address"].str.split(")").str[-1]  so that I could return the target result back to text["address"], or there would be a ValueError: columns must be same length as key.   Thanks!